# How to achieve Expandablelistview child custom layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin, xamarin.android, expandablelistview

I can't figure out how to achieve this in android. I have a layout like this:

[image]

I want it such that on click of the plus button it will display the full layout like this:

[image]

This layout is the child of an expandablelistview item. So when the expandablelistview item is clicked it shows a short lost of items in that category. Then, if the user wants to see all, he will click the plus button.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Create an XML layout with the name expandable_list_layout

```
<ExpandableListView
    android:id="@+id/data_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/dynamicHeadingTxt"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
    android:layout_weight="8"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00ffffff"
    android:childDivider="@drawable/child_separator"
    android:divider="@drawable/child_separator"
    android:groupIndicator="@null" >
</ExpandableListView>
```

Create a custom adapter. Let`s call it InboxExpandableListAdapter. This class should extend BaseExpandableListAdapter and override

```
public class ada extends BaseExpandableListAdapter{

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
        boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
        View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}
}
```

If you look here, the overriden method takes two arguments i.e., a groupposition and a childposition. These suggest that we should supply the adapter with some kind of list which must contain groups and their child. I am creating a constructor for the class

```
public InboxExpandableListAdapter(Activity context, List<String> data, List<String> data_secondry,
        List< List<String>> dataCollections) {
    this.context = context;
    this.dataCollections = dataCollections;
    this.data = data;
    this.data_secondry = data_secondry;
}
```

Now getChildView method and getGroupView populates the view for each item. So inside these methods, inflate the layout which you want to show for group and their respective child

```
public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
        boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final String data = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.child_item, null);
    }

    TextView item = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.data);

    item.setText(data);
    return convertView;
}

public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
        View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    String laptopName = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.group_item,
                null);
    }

    TextView item = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.data);
    item.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    item.setText(laptopName);
    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: In getChildView method, context.getLayoutInflater() is showing error

Answer (score 0):

[`CoordinatorLayout`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout.html) is the thing which designed for such cases. Have a look at the example in [Android Developers blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.com.au/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html)

Alternatively, you might have two layouts grouped - one is the topmost upper row and another one - other rows beneath it. Then handle "+" button `Click` event on which you'd reveal the latter one (with possible animation).

I'd proceed with `CoordinatorLayout` as this is preferable approach, however feel free to try both and see what suits you better.

Comment: I have read up on CoordinatorLayout and I'm still not clear how this is achievable with this. Kindly provide more guidance to this. Thanks