# Expandablelistview With Custom Child Layout in Android

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I have been searching around google for two days but it is very hard found any luck with my problem. what I'm trying to achieve is I want to create an `ExpandableListView` in which every child has two value one to the right and another to the left, following question: [How to achieve Expandablelistview child custom layout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32986839/how-to-achieve-expandablelistview-child-custom-layout) was relevant but not fully as there are some elements which were missing

[image: ExpandableListView View Design]

This how I want to design my user interface, my array is something like this

`[Parent 1 =[{Child 1, Child 1.1},{child 2,child 2.1},{child 3,child 3.1},{child 4, child 4.1},{child 5, child 5.1}],Parent 1=[{}]]`

so on and so forth, now please help me out with the solution so that I can create a UI something like given

Comment: You can make custom class for your child. Try my sample to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50092400/values-of-counter-changes-after-scrolling-expendablelistview/50103780#50103780 Hope that helps!

Comment: @I_A_Mok thank for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this `CustomAdapter` and use custom `enter code here`layout as you want just create your `layout.xml` and use in this `adapter`

and try to Improve your `R&d skills` it is not a very big task , you spend two days to achieve it. any site does not provide `code` as you want thay only guide us, we need to improve that code as per our requirement

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
    Context context;
    ArrayList<WeblListHeader> webHeader;

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<WeblListHeader> webHeader) {
        this.context = context;
        this.webHeader = webHeader;
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return webHeader.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int i) {
        return webHeader.get(i).getAl_state().size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int i) {
        return webHeader.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int i, int i1) {
        return webHeader.get(i).getAl_state().get(i1);
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int i, int i1) {
        return i1;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int i, boolean isExpanded, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        if (view==null){

            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.your_expend_header_layout, null);
        }
        TextView tv_state = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv_name);

        ImageView iconExpend = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.iconExpend);
        if (isExpanded) {
            iconExpend.setImageResource(R.drawable.arrow_up_selected);
            tv_state.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.selectedText));
        } else {
            iconExpend.setImageResource(R.drawable.arrow_down_unselect);
            tv_state.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
        }

        tv_state.setText(webHeader.get(i).getStr_country());
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(final int i, final int i1, boolean b, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        if (view==null){

            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.your_child_layout, null);
        }

        TextView tv_state = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv_name);

        tv_state.setText(webHeader.get(i).getAl_state().get(i1).getStr_name());
        tv_state.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

            }
        });
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int i, int i1) {
        return false;
    }
```

let me know if it works for you and if any issue in this.